# SDL2, FreeBSD and CodeBlocks - how to link libraries

Tags: sdl, freebsd

I started using FreeBSD about 3 months ago. Before, I used to code on Windows with CodeBlocks and never had any problems. I was writing SDL2 games like Snake and Tetris. But I want to do the same on FreeBSD, which is somehow new for me, like every Linux system.

**I want to link SDL2 libraries to the CodeBlocks on FreeBSD, but I can't manage to do this. I'm doing sth like in Windows:**

In Compiler settings >> Search directories >> Compiler I set /usr/local/include/SDL2, which is a path to the SDL2 headers

In Compiler settings >> Search directories >> Linker I set /usr/local/lib, which seems to be the path to the SDL2 libraries, like "libSDL2..." etc.

Additionally I'm adding in Compiler settings >> Linker settings >> Other linker options phrases like "-lSDL2main -lSDL2 etc."

**It seems to be the same options set like in Windows, but it can't find -lSDL2main, that's the kind of problem.**

On the other hand I tried to link libraries this way Compiler settings >> Linker settings >> Link libraries and I chose all libraries like libSDL....so or with .a extension, but got "Linker problem error 1"

I'm trying to compile with clang, but I don't think so that difference between gcc and clang is a problem here. So... how to link it?

Give me some advices and explain why I'm wrong, please :)

Part of code (how I'm trying to include headers):

```
#include </usr/local/include/SDL2/SDL.h>
```

`#include "header.h"`

A. S.

Comment: `pkg info -lx sdl` will show you the list of files installed by sdl package. Find out which directory contains library you need.

Comment: Great advice, dude! I found out that there is another folder called "libdata" where are dependencies! I linked it and finally I can compile SDL2 code in CodeBlocks! No warnings, no errors! YEAH! :))))

Comment: But overally I found out real solution. The problem was that I wanted to compile it as 32 bit app, and that's why I had problems with linker. I just recovered previous settings like in thread and wrote #include <SDL.h> and it works. Thanks anyway!